# Generic indexer overload specialization

Tags: c#, generics, template-specialization

I know that there isn't template specialization in C#, but this works(at least in compile time):

```
    public T test0<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    // handling T=float case
    public float test0()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

and this doesn't even compile:

```
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return default(T); }
        set { }
    }

    public float this[int i]
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
```

nor this

```
    public float this<float>[int i]
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
```

it says ".. already defines a member called 'this' with the same parameter types" on the float version. I could check for all types in the generic `[]` accessor but too many `if-elseif`s and `typeof()`s would decrease performance(I'm going to use this as an unmanaged array instead of a managed array) and `dynamic` is not an option as I'm using .Net 3.5 mainly. In another question, I've learned that I can't get pointer of a generic type so I decided to use multiple overloads per float,double,int and byte type and use those overloads in this array access overload(but not in same method but different ones to not lose performance.)

Can a generic `[]` be overloaded by some of primitive types like `float`? More specifically, can a class by only itself be used like below example, ever?

```
MyArr<float> arr = new MyArr<float>();

// specifically rounds to nearest for floats
arr[100]+=500f;

MyArr<int> arr = new MyArr<int>();

// specifically adds 1 to some performance counter variable
arr[100]+=500;

MyArr<byte> arr = new MyArr<byte>();

// does nothing special
arr[100]+=50;
```

if answer is no, then I'm going to use an extra `Interface` to implement this feature, but I'm not sure it's okay to add another interface to project just for a single feature. (should I ask "is adding another interface just for a single method okay?" in another question?)

Comment: in the first case you have two different overloads, one takes generic type parameter as well, while for indexer you have same signatures except return type is different so cannot be overloaded

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you mean this can only be done by implementing a custom interface, not possible with a single class definition?

Comment: i am not completely sure, may be there is way, let's see if someone answers it

Comment: premature optimization? there may be little to no difference to be expected between a fictional template specialization/overload resolution and a typeof(T)-based conditional version.

Comment: @dlatikay when more types are added in, there would be 20-30 different versions so checking if-else for 30 times just to do `c[i]=a[i]+b[i]` would take longer than simply using arrays. Reason I'm asking this is, C++ side is already optimized, gpgpu part is ready and optimized and only this C# access part is left to optimize. I'm optimizing the bottlenecking part. Example: someone initializes array with this in 2 seconds but gpgpu takes 0.5 seconds. But with C++ arrays and pointers, both takes 0.5s

Comment: @dlatikay and I cant use generic pointers in C# which forced me to do this

Comment: When you access `myObject[42]`, which overload of the indexer would you expect to be called?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper if it is assigned to a float container, float one(I thought the second overload would hide the first one). if int, then generic or another overload if exists

Comment: Indexer cannot contain generic parameters (just like property). One option is to remove indexer and just use regular method: `Get<T>(int index) {} Set<T>(int index, T value);`. Yes, not very convenient but if you are doing perfomance optimization - that might be an option.

Comment: @Evk I was hoping to write a "pure-C# array looking" multi-gpu library without touching IL or too many interfaces(or code duplications) but it looks like very hard without.

Comment: If you are going to provide multiple overloads for each type that you are going to handle, then what is the purpose 'generic'?

Comment: Well indexer defines both getter and setter. With setter runtime can choose a correct overload to call, but if your example could work, how can runtime decide which indexer to call when you do `array[X]`, so calling a getter?

Comment: @thangadurai at least other methods are not duplicated. This array accessing is the only issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following might be helpful:

```
public class GenericType<T>
{
    public virtual T Test0()
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    public virtual T this[int i]
    {
        get { return default(T); }
        set { }
    }
}

public class FloatType : GenericType<float>
{
    public override float Test0()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override float this[int i]
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set {  }
    }
}


GenericType<float> nonOptimizedFloat = new GenericType<float>();
var defVal = nonOptimizedFloat[3]; // will use the non-optimized version

GenericType<float> optimizedFloat = new FloatType();
defVal = optimizedFloat[3]; // will use the optimized version
```

You can have as many optimized types as you'd like and still keep some common logic in the base class.

You can also consider defining the base class as abstract and ensure that the optimized versions will always be used.

Comment: Or I just make `this [int i]` abstract instead of whole class, then make other methods virtual, so others not needed to re-written for each type? (similar to using interface, forcing only some to be implemented in child classes). Does interface behave same as your solution when type changes in runtime ?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, this is up to you. you don't have to declare the others as virtual if you don't want them to be overriden. Anyhow, the class itself has to be abstract as well.

Comment: Because of the rule? If any method is abstract, class itself has to be abstract too?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And about the interfaces - they won't help if you need some common implementations

Comment: if I write `MyArr<byte> arr = new MyArr<byte>();` ? Does it use ByteType class or base class(`MyArr`)  as in your answer(your answer has only virtual, not abstract) ? I wanted to have same writing style for all types but its not possible? Now I'm not away from computer, I'll try myself, thanks anyway

Comment: Abstract cant be instantiated so no way for "same written" +"differently optimized"

Comment: But at least optimized ones will be given implicitly by library, other developers will see only one type of thing(only making a field true/false makes it optimized). So only I will see the different writings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `helper class` which contains a `nested generic class` with `Func/Action` delegate to implement specialization of Indexer/Property/Method.

```
internal static class IndexerImpl
{
    private static T IndexerDefaultImpl<T>(int i) => default(T); //default implementation

    private static T IndexerImpl2<T>(int i) => default(T); //another implementation for short/int/long

    private static string IndexerForString(int i) => (i * i).ToString(); //specialization for T=string
    private static DateTime IndexerForDateTime(int i) => new DateTime(i * i * i); //specialization for T=DateTime

    static IndexerImpl() //install the specializations
    {
        Specializer<string>.Fun = IndexerForString;
        Specializer<DateTime>.Fun = IndexerForDateTime;

        Specializer<short>.Fun = IndexerImpl2<short>;
        Specializer<int>.Fun = IndexerImpl2<int>;
        Specializer<long>.Fun = IndexerImpl2<long>;
    }

    internal static class Specializer<T> //specialization dispatcher
    {
        internal static Func<int, T> Fun;
        internal static T Call(int i)
            => null != Fun
                ? Fun(i)
                : IndexerDefaultImpl<T>(i);
    }
}

public class YourClass<T>
{
    public T this[int i] => IndexerImpl.Specializer<T>.Call(i);
}
```

If you need the instance of `YourClass` to calculate the return value, you can add a paramter to pass the needed information:

```
internal static class IndexerImpl
{
    private static T IndexerDefaultImpl<T>(int i, YourClass<T> yourClass) => default(T); //default implementation

    private static T IndexerImpl2<T>(int i, YourClass<T> yourClass) => default(T); //another implementation for short/int/long

    private static string IndexerForString<T>(int i, YourClass<T> yourClass) => (i * i).ToString(); //specialization for T=string
    private static DateTime IndexerForDateTime<T>(int i, YourClass<T> yourClass) => new DateTime(i * i * i); //specialization for T=DateTime

    static IndexerImpl() //install the specializations
    {
        Specializer<string>.Fun = IndexerForString;
        Specializer<DateTime>.Fun = IndexerForDateTime;

        Specializer<short>.Fun = IndexerImpl2;
        Specializer<int>.Fun = IndexerImpl2;
        Specializer<long>.Fun = IndexerImpl2;
    }

    internal static class Specializer<T> //specialization dispatcher
    {
        internal static Func<int, YourClass<T>, T> Fun;
        internal static T Call(int i, YourClass<T> yourClass)
            => null != Fun
                ? Fun(i, yourClass)
                : IndexerDefaultImpl(i, yourClass);
    }
}

public class YourClass<T>
{
    public T this[int i] => IndexerImpl.Specializer<T>.Call(i, this);
}
```

When specializing a generic Indexer, a **non-generic** helper class is needed.

When specializing a generic Property/Method of non-generic class, the `default implementation`/`specializations` and `nested specialization dispatcher class` can be put directly in your class.

What you have to pay attention is, do not put installation of specializations into static constructor of a **generic** class.

---

Additionally, if you need partial specialization, you can use a generic helper class, with  parameterized types which do not need to specialize:

```
internal static class GetValueImpl<R, S>
{
    private static T DefImpl<T>(R r, S s) => default(T);
    private static int IntRet(R r, S s) => int.MaxValue;

    internal static class Specializer<T>
    {
        internal static Func<R, S, T> Fun;
        internal static T Call(R r, S s) => null != Fun ? Fun(r, s) : DefImpl<T>(r, s);
    }

    static GetValueImpl()
    {
        Specializer<int>.Fun = IntRet;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    //R and S are not specialized, we are specializing T
    public T GetValue<R, S, T>(R r, S s) => GetValueImpl<R, S>.Specializer<T>.Call(r, s);
}
```

Using this way to implement partial specialization, you have to aware that, the static constructor of helper class will run multiple times if you call nested specializer class multiple times with different non-specialized types:

```
public void Test()
{
     var foo = new TestClass();

     //GetValueImpl<long, long> will be created at runtime
     var v1 = foo.GetValue<long, long, int>(1, 2);    //GetValueImpl<long, long>.Specializer<int> will be called, specialized
     var v2 = foo.GetValue<long, long, string>(1, 2); //GetValueImpl<long, long>.Specializer<string> will be called
     var v3 = foo.GetValue<long, long, long>(1, 2);   //GetValueImpl<long, long>.Specializer<long> will be called

     //GetValueImpl<long, int> will be created at runtime
     var v4 = foo.GetValue<long, int, int>(1, 2);     //GetValueImpl<long, int>.Specializer<int> will be called, specialized
     var v5 = foo.GetValue<long, int, double>(1, 2);  //GetValueImpl<long, int>.Specializer<double> will be called
}
```

Note that the static constructor will run 2 times for `GetValueImpl<long, long>` and `GetValueImpl<long, int>`, so do not put extra code in static constructor of helper class.